# sleep mode in neoway

Tags: c, embedded, gsm

In Neoway N10 GSM module am using `setTime`, `setALARM` and `sleep` function in our application. By using setALARM function I set 1 minute wake-up time and call sleep function to run continuously for every 1 minute.

The first time I run it, it enters sleep mode and wakes up after 1 minute. But the second time it enters the sleep mode and does not wake up. What could be the the reason for this issue?

```c
void RTC_Function(void)
{
    rtc_time.rtc_min=1;
    rtc_time.rtc_sec=0;
    Neoway_SetTime(&rtc_time); //set system time
    Neoway_SetAlarm(&rtc_time,2); //Set the alarm to triggered after 1 min
    Neoway_Sleep(NEOWAY_TRUE); //calling sleep mode
}
```

For reference:

`S32 Neoway_Sleep(NeowayBoolEnum is_sleep)` - Enable or disable sleeping mode of the module, when in sleeping mode, the module’s power consumption can be reduced to 2 mA if no SMS, Call, GPRS data, or interruption going on.

`is_sleep`: `NEOWAY_FALSE` : disable the sleeping mode, `NEOWAY_TRUE`: enable the sleeping mode

`void Neoway_SetAlarm(NeowayRtcStruct * rtc_time,U8 condition)` - Set the time and other conditions to trigger the alarm.

`rtc_time`: the time of the alarm

`condition`: triggering condition, values are as follows

- 0 disable alarm triggering
- 1 trigger the alarm when reaching the same second.
- 2 trigger the alarm when reaching the same minute and second.
- 3 trigger the alarm when reaching the same hour, minute and second.
- 4 trigger the alarm when reaching the same day, hour, minute and second.
- 6 trigger the alarm when reaching the same month, day, hour, minute and second.
- 7 trigger the alarm when reaching the same year, month, day, hour, minute and second.

Link for documentation - http://wless.ru/files/GSM/Neoway/N10/Neoway_N10_OpenCPU_API_Description_V1.0.pdf

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to style your question. In particular, use the `{}` button to format the code as such.

Comment: Please post your whole code!

Comment: sorry i can't  share code. Please let know which are the peripherals is remain active when N10 module in sleep mode?

Comment: It is really required to know when `RTC_Function()` gets called. If you can share when that function gets called (I mean on what condition and what time), it may help!